# Vue - TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, promise, scope, request, action

```js
  methods: {
  
    sendTemplate(){
      let c = "<div>something</div>";
      
      //post request 
   
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request('post', 'template', {data:c})
          .then( (response) => {

            if(response.status == 200){

                   this.$store.dispatch({  //<----- "this" is not undefined
                      type: 'createAction',
                      data: response.dataObj
                    });
            }
          })
          .catch( error => console.log(error) );
      });
      //end of post request 

      });
    },
}
```

I understand that the scope of "this.$store.dispatch" is not pointing to vue, but its already inside a arrow function in this promise so I thought its implicitly scoped?

I'm sure it's probably something really simple that I'm not seeing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suggest putting in `console.log(this)` at various points to see exactly where the `this` gets dropped. That will also help to confirm it isn't a caching problem.

Comment: THAT WAS IT!!! I realized after a couple console.logs that it was undefined in the whole function because I didnt close a prior function. How do I give you points for correct answer lol.